# How can I convert this SQL query using multiple joins and sub-queries into Perl DBIx::Class?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

Any ideas? Anyone tackled this before?

```
select c.parent_id, c.category_id, c.name, count(*)
  from categories c
  join product_categories pc
    on c.category_id      = pc.category_id
  join authorizations a
    on pc.product_id      = a.product_id
  join set_authorizations sa
    on a.authorization_id = sa.authorization_id
 where a.active           = 1
   and sa.set_id          = 2
   and c.parent_id in (
    select category_id
      from categories
     where parent_id is null
       )
 group by c.parent_id, c.category_id, c.name;
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have the DBIx::Class definitions of your tables and foreign keys already?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something that is not quite easily accomplished. As dgw correctly stated, you have to make some homework first, defining your model objects - with DBIx::Class, or Rose::DB::Object, or whatever ORM you'd favor. Only then working with these objects will become a trivial task, no matter how complex they are.

But there's another way: using SQL::Abstract module, and its 'extension', SQL::Abstract::More. If you only need to abstract your queries, make them 'perlish' instead of 'sqlish', I suppose that's just what the doctor ordered. )

For example, your query in SQL::Abstract::More will sound like that:

```
my ($sql, @bind) = $sqla->select(
  -columns => [ qw/c.parent_id c.category_id c.name COUNT(*)/ ],
  -from    => [-join => qw/
        categories|c 
          category_id=category_id   product_categories|pc 
          product_id=product_id     authorizations|a
          authorization_id=authorization_id set_authorizations|sa
        /],
  -where   => { 
    'a.active'  => 1, 
    'sa.set_id' => 2, 
    'c.parent_id' => \["IN (SELECT category_id FROM categories WHERE parent_id IS NULL)"], 
  },
  -group_by => [qw/ c.parent_id c.category_id c.name /],
);
```

That's still quite formidable, though... Perhaps creating a VIEW with all the joined tables will make the code (and, I suppose, the performance) more digestible? )